# Replace WCF by gRPC with associated protocols

Tags: wcf, .net-core, grpc

I have .Net framework application with WCF services. I am using different sets of protocols such as NetTCP and NetNamedPipes. I am migrating these services to .Net Core with gRPC. As gRPC only supports HTTP/2, is there any way for client application to be remain untouched while this migration or is there any way gRPC support NetTCP protocol?

References:

https://codemag.com/Article/1911102/gRPC-as-a-Replacement-for-WCF

https://www.seeleycoder.com/blog/migrating-wcf-to-grpc-netcore/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GRPC is based on http2, and while `nettcpbinding` is efficient, the gRPC is the best approach for building distributed applications, http2 has achieved equivalent speed and performance, and in some cases, even better. Also, GRPC only supports http2 as far as I know. Please refer to the below links.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/architecture/grpc-for-wcf-developers/network-protocols
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/architecture/grpc-for-wcf-developers/wcf-bindings
Feel free to let me know if there is anything I can help with.